# Bootstrap modal window in Laravel app not showing

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I'm writing a Laravel app and trying to implement a modal showing some details on an element. When I'm clicking on the link the backdrop is showing but not the modal window. In the network monitor of chrome it is showing the modal window in preview.

What's wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Here is my code

**index.blade.php**

```php
<td>
<a href="{{ route('projects.show', $project->id) }}" class="btn btn-info" data-remote="true">Details</a>
</td>
```

**modal.blade.php**

```php
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">@yield('title')</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          @yield('content')
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          @yield('footer')
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**show.blade.php**

```php
@extends('layouts.modal')
@section('title')
Demo Modal
@endsection
@section('content')
<p>test</p>
@endsection
@section('footer')
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
@endsection
```

**remote.js**

```
$(document).on('ajax:success', function(e, xhr){
    if(!$('#modal').length){
        $('body').append($('<div class="modal" id="modal"></div>'))
    }
   $('#modal').html(xhr.responseText).modal('show');
});
```

***ProjectController.php***

```php
public function show($id)
    {
        $project = Project::findOrFail($id);

        return view('projects.show', compact('project'));
    }
```

Comment: are you trying to call the modal after the ajax success? and did you see your element html using inspect element?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in browser `console`?

Comment: @DhananjayKyada nope I'm getting no errors?

Comment: @Jovs in the js file you see all I'm doing with it. I don't see the html element when I use the inspector

Comment: then that means your ajax is not success

Comment: I didn't change anything but now I see some code of the modal in the inspector. but it seems that the main part is missing. <div class="modal fade show" id="modal" style="display: block;" aria-modal="true"></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey never use  HTML Element in making a clickable modals that has value on it.
I suggest you used  add value on it , That can be "ID" then add modal attributes on it, Then boom everything is fine and working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the html id tag in your link.

I suggest you try this

```
<a data-toggle="modal" id="smallButton" data-target="#smallModal"
 data-attr="{{ route('projects.show', $project->id) }}" title="show">
 <i class="fas fa-eye text-success  fa-lg"></i>
</a>

<!-- small modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="smallModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="smallModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="smallBody">
                <div>
                    <!-- the result to be displayed apply here -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    // display a modal (small modal)
    $(document).on('click', '#smallButton', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let href = $(this).attr('data-attr');
        $.ajax({
            url: href,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#loader').show();
            },
            // return the result
            success: function(result) {
                $('#smallModal').modal("show");
                $('#smallBody').html(result).show();
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#loader').hide();
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, testStatus, error) {
                console.log(error);
                alert("Page " + href + " cannot open. Error:" + error);
                $('#loader').hide();
            },
            timeout: 8000
        })
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Remote.js file :

```
$(document).on('ajax:success', function(e, xhr){
    if(!$('#modal').length){
        $('body').append($('<div class="modal" id="modal"></div>'))
    }
   $('#modal').modal('show');
   $('#modal').html(xhr.responseText);
});
```